# Ethereum contract UI

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I am new to block chain and Ethereum and I have question regarding it.

**As per my understanding**

Ethereum is a decentralized platform that runs smart contracts: applications that run exactly as programmed without any possibility of downtime, censorship, fraud or third party interference. When the smart contract is deployed, the network propagate to executable code into the network and this way each node can run the smart contract.

**But what if we need to build an application with GUI which provide graphical screen to interact with the smart contract. How our GUI will be deployed to each node? How do we push it? What is the mechanism for it?**

Comment: Does everyone is doing the same as you suggested, i mean does most of the people publish their GUI on centralize location or what??

Answer (score 2):

The GUI is typically written in JavaScript and published like a traditional website. See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/.

If you want to decentralize the front-end, you can deploy it to IPFS or Swarm, which are distributes storage solutions.